# What is the difference between Zend\Db Result and ResultSet?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I've tried both documented methods of fetching using a [Zend\Db\Sql\Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html):

```
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

and

```
$selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
$results = $adapter->query($selectString, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

The first method returns a Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result (instance of ResultInterface) while the second returns Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet (ResultSetInterface). The ResultSet has a toArray() method while Result doesn't.

Why are there two different types for results and what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Quiet old question, but I had the same one (did not to see the forest for the trees) when I looked into project Laminas (https://getlaminas.org/). In short:

- work with/use Result for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.
- work with/use ResutlSet for SELECT, use $resultSet->initialize($result) for data transfer/initialization

Long answer:

```
Laminas\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface extends Countable, Iterator
```

e.g.

```
Laminas\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result implements Iterator, ResultInterface
```

Result is the basic object for returning a result. Here you also have a method current() to get data, but here you exclusively have methods like getAffectedRows() and getGeneratedValue(). (*For the latter, also a $adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue() may be of interest.*)
Additionally here you have the method isQueryResult(), which is for example used as a switch in $adapter->query(). isQueryResult() only returns TRUE for a SELECT-Statement (*even if its result is empty and count() == 0*), otherwise it returns FALSE for INSERT, UPDATE, ...

For example Laminas-Db for PDO always (and only) returns a Result object for a $statement->execute($params).
On the other hand $adapter->query($sql) is a "convenience function".

- by default it prepares a Statement object and returns it
- if parameters are provided, it will directly execute the implicitly generated Statement and return a result,
- if flag QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE is used (which is only possible for plain SQL, because in this case you cannot provide a parameter-array for replacement), the query is also directly executed.

If query() directly executes SQL, the returned object depends on the query type. If the Result object confirms a SELECT statement (check with isQueryResult()), it injects the data into a cloned ResultSet object. For all other queries, it directly returns the original Result object.

On the other hand:

```
Laminas\Db\ResultSet\ResultSetInterface extends Traversable, Countable
```

```
Laminas\Db\ResultSet\AbstractResultSet implements Iterator, ResultSetInterface
```

```
Laminas\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet extends AbstractResultSet
```

is essentially used to iterate over "real" result sets (*and data*), generated by SELECT statements. It has no constructor. You have to use its initialize($dataSource) method to provide data with possible types: array|Iterator|IteratorAggregate|ResultInterface.
For example the "convenience function" $adapter->query($sql) does this implicitly for SELECT queries and returns a ResultSet instead of a Result for these queries.

Additionally you have to use $adapter->query($sql, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE) for statements, that cannot be prepared, for example DDL statements (and here you also have to work with Result instead of a ResultSet; an ALTER TABLE does not return data ;-)